# Blazor dll loaded many times => insufficient resources in chrome

Tags: .net, load, blazor

I have an .NET 5 blazor app, using Web Assembly hosted feature.
In a page, there are many iframes targetting SSRS, with a src field of type "https://x.y.z.t?SSRS/blahblah".
When I pubblish my app, the login page works well, but the page with all the iframes is loaded many times : I mean all blazor stuff is loaded many times(more or less 26!) and it makes some of the last requests fail with an INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES error.

Here is an example of what chrome dev tools show me:
[[image]
The file shown here is dotnet.wasm.

Do you know the reason of this behavior?

EDIT:
I would like to add that the iframes contain a parameter:

```
<iframe id="iFrameTest" src=@($"{Tools.IframeAddress}?%2fSSRS%2fKPIs&rc:Section=12&rs:Command=Embed&HospitalParam={{{LocalizationBanner.SelectedSpeciality.Service.Site.Hospital.Id.ToString().ToUpper()}}}&SiteParam={{{LocalizationBanner.SelectedSpeciality.Service.Site.Id.ToString().ToUpper()}}}&ServiceParam={{{LocalizationBanner.SelectedSpeciality.Service.Id.ToString().ToUpper()}}}&SpecialityParam={{{LocalizationBanner.SelectedSpeciality.Id.ToString().ToUpper()}}}") scrolling="no" style="width:625px;height:700px" frameborder="0" />
```

where Tools.IFrameAddress is defined from the HostEnvironment.BaseAddress (it is a static variable).
Am I wrong in the src string format?

Comment: Just throwing spaghetti at the wall, but are you using a singlet service inside your iframes?

Comment: sorry but I don't understand your question, the razor page contains a lot of iframes, each one with an uri in the src field.

Comment: if you are asking for a singleton service, for example HttpClient, I have an HttpClient injected in the page, but it does not appear in the iframes' uris.

Comment: It seems to me that the browser is treating each iframe as a separate instance, requiring it to load the entire logic again.  I've never used SSRS-- does yours serve a WASM page?

Comment: yes, a hosted wasm. I made some tests, and it appears that if there is 1 iframe, the dll are loaded one time. 2 iframes, they are loaded 2 times, etc. Everything is ok in dev, but on azure I get the problem. plz see my edit.

Comment: I saw that Program.Main is relaunched many times too. It's not a simple page reloading.

Comment: iframes are for all intents and purposes a separate window/tab as far as resources are concerned. It should be unsurprising that 26 separate instances of your app will introduce problems.  In my opinion, you should strongly reconsider your use of iframes.  Why _are_ you using iframes anyway?  (sincere question)

Comment: well, Iframes were available. And they use the browser credentials, it's simple to use.

Comment: iframes are more or less obsolete.  (there are rare occasions when they make sense)  Generally, you really shouldn't use them, and certainly not for your purposes.

Comment: That was my first steps in blazor.

Comment: Blazor is VERY good at segmenting stuff on the screen, is all about re-usable components, has very good coverage for JSON web apis.  You COULD make your site work with iframes, but in my opinion that's going to harm your development in Blazor a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think at this point I have enough info to make a recommendation.  Don't use iframes at all.  Instead, use a web api to transfer only raw data (probably as a serialized JSON object), then unpack that JSON on the client side and present it with multiple instances of a Blazor component.

I recommend starting with the following or with a YouTube equivalent (I've seen several good YouTube tutorials specifically about using a web api in Blazor):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-web-api?view=aspnetcore-5.0

*Note: make sure you read the section on Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS).  It's right at the bottom of the page, but it's important.*

If you have specific questions about any step of this process, I recommend opening a new question.

Answer (score 0):

After many hours of search, I found the answer. The iframes src were of type : "http://x.y.z.t/ReportService/blahblah" and "/ReportService" was here for catching the calls for Ssrs, but the port was still the default one, 80, and at the address "http://x.y.z.t:80" there is my app.
Then all the iframes triggered a reload of the base page of my app. sorry, I did not give you the entire src of the iframes.

Comment: To avoid this, one way I see would be to use virtual directories. Thus

Comment: I'm glad you found your solution!